# Difference between linear and quasi linear differential equation. Which is more strong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am currently studying PDE for the first time. So I came across some definitions of linear differential operator and quasi-linear differential operator. 
What exactly is the difference? Can someone explain in simple words?

This is the definition in my script

[image]

Comment: Let $F(x,u,u')=0$ be a first-order ODE for the function $u(x)$.  We say that it is **linear** whenever it can be written as $a(x)u+b(x)u'=0$ for functions $a$ and $b$.  We say that it's **quasilinear** if it can be written as $G(x,u)+b(x,u)u'=0$.  Note that in this case, $G$ is a nonlinear part, and $b$ is a function of $x$ and $u$ instead of just $x$.  This is the "one-by-one" case, i.e. first-order in a single variable $x$. The "two-by-two" case is given in the answer I posted.

Comment: Check out the Chapter 3 of the book: Partial differential equations of applied mathematics, Zauder,1989

Answer (score 3):

It's helpful to consider the "two by two" case, i.e. second-order PDEs in $x$ and $y$.  Recall that such a PDE always has the form $$F(x,y,u,u_x,u_y,u_{xy},u_{yx},u_{xx},u_{yy})=0$$ for some function $F$.  This PDE is called **linear** whenever it can be written
$$
a(x,y)u+b(x,y)u_x+c(x,y)u_y+d(x,y)u_{xy}+e(x,y)u_{yx}+f(x,y)u_{xx}+g(x,y)u_{yy}=0
$$
which we will abbreviate
$$
au+bu_x+cu_y+du_{xy}+eu_{yx}+fu_{xx}+gu_{yy}=0
$$
The **quasilinear** case is different in two respects.  First of all, the original function $F$ need only be linear in derivatives of the highest order (in this case $\text{ord}=2$).  That is to say, it can be written as
$$
G(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)+du_{xy}+eu_{yx}+fu_{xx}+gu_{yy}=0
$$
for some (possibly nonlinear) function $G$.  The second difference is this: the remaining coefficients of the "linear part" (or **principal part**) can depend on $u$, $u_x$, and $u_y$ as well as $x$ and $y$.  In particular, we should write
$$
G(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)+d(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)u_{xy}+e(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)u_{yx}+f(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)u_{xx}+g(x,y,u,u_x,u_y)u_{yy}=0
$$