# Why is Liouville PDE quasilinear?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the PDE of Liouville $$u_t - \sum_{i=1}^n(b_iu)_{x_i} = 0$$

where

$u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (with $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$) is the unknown function

$u_{x_i} := \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}$ is the partial derivative

$b:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

How can one show that this PDE is quasilinear?

Comment: It's not just quasilinear, it's linear

Comment: Because $(b_iu)_{x_i}$ doesn't destroy linearity, right? How can one show formally that this PDE is linear?

Comment: If the left side is $L(u)$ and $s,t$ are constants, $L(s u + t v) = s L(u) + t L(v)$.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @RobertIsrael ! If you formulate an answer, I'll be happy to give you credit :) Cheers

Comment: BTW, Im curious, how would one show quasilinearity? And semilinearity for that sake?

Comment: Using the definition ? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As requested]
It's not just quasilinear, it's linear.

If the left side is $L(u)$, and $s$ and $t$ are constants, 
$L(s u + t v) = s L(u) + t L(v)$.  That's the definition of linear.

For quasilinear, see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537821/difference-between-linear-and-quasi-linear-differential-equation-which-is-more).  So e.g. 
$$ a(t,x, u) u_t + b(t,x,u) + \sum_i c_i(t,x,u) u_{x_i} = 0$$
would be quasilinear.